# sending body text in the mail with HTML using PHP,codeiginiter

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
I have a dynamic data stored in variable, I want to send the dynamic data in email as body text. when i am trying to send the data through mail,it is sending in one line. I want to send data as it is I written.I want to send with spaces and with new lines.

i got this output:

 Dear chandra, This is to Confirm your inperson Interview on 2016-06-19 00:00:00. Below Mentioned are the venue and contact details for your Convenience. please fill feedback form after completed Interview See below links
ThanksShiva,HR   


i need as below format :


     Dear chandra,
               This is to Confirm your inperson Interview on 2016-06-19 00:00:00. Below Mentioned are the venue and contact details for your Convenience.
     Thanks
     shiva,
     HR



$messageinterviewer = $this->input->post('messageinterviewer');// i get data
$feedbackurl = $this->input->post('feedbackurl');


    $messagewithfeedbackurl = $messageinterviewer;
    $messagewithfeedbackurl .= $feedbackurl;
```

$this->sendMailToInterviewer ($tointerviewer,$frominterviewer,$ccinterviewer,$subjectinterviewer,$messagewithfeedbackurl);

Comment: pleaseformat the question. Best way to achieve understandable helpful answers, if posing readable questions (four leading spaces format code, aligned with left margin normal text) there are help buttons on format here ;-)

Answer (score 0):

First of all please format your question in a better way as it is hard to understand in this way. Leaving that aside you can use PHPMailer with CI and send HTML emails in the following way:

```
    $mail->isHTML(true);

    $mail->Body = '
        <html>
        <head>
            <title>..your title..</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <h3>..message heading..</h3>
        <p>Dear Receiver_Name,</p><br>
        <p>..message body.. </p><br><br>
        <p>Thanks</p>
        <p>..sender_name..</p>
        </body>
        </html>
    ';
```